# Drupal 6 Calendar send mail notification

Tags: drupal, module, calendar, drupal-modules, icalendar

I am using Drupal 6 and the calendar module, I wonder how can I allow users to put their own events on the calendar, I need to add email notification 24 hours before the event to the event creator.

I guess it can be done with a cron job running sql query but I need that sql query please...

if anyone also can suggest a better solution that wil be great !

Comment: Perhaps you should look into triggers and actions instead. It sounds like that would be a suitable option.

Comment: I don't need the mail to be sent when the user add event, I want the mail to be sent 24 hours before the event happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a function to select the events and their creators and loop on them and send mail, and called this function inside the hook_cron() it worked fine this way